# Force Laravel 5.4 to always start related entity pagination from page 1

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-pagination

I have a Post model that can have many comments. When I'm listing posts in a feed - both posts and post comments are paginated.
The problem is when I visit post feed page that isn't first - post comments aren't paginated starting from the first page. They are starting from the same page as posts.

[image]

Is there a way to always force Laravel to start related entity pagination from page 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the reason why it happens is that the both paginators use the same `page` query parameter value by default. See the [code](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/99469b6499c1e404c78a70c9c58812c7da5f45ec/Query/Builder.php#L1723).

You can change this behavior by providing the third parameter of the `paginate()` method call to something like 'comments_page'.

```
$post->comments()->paginate(15, ['*'], 'comments_page');
```

Now when you want to see the first page of the comments you can pass the `comments_page` query parameter value into the query string.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/feeds/all-posts?page=2&comments_page=1
```

Comment: Hi. My problem was a little bit more complex, but your answer gave me good clue. Tnx